# structure of sending data of a control for Json?

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, jquery

Hi Iam using JSON for ASP.Net and doing it by WebMethods.

here is my Ajax call for that webmethod.

```
       $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            url: "Voyage.aspx/V_Set",
            data: { 'Action': $('#txtNumber').val(), 'ID': $('#txtTag').val(), 'StartlID': $('#txtTag').val()},
            async: true,
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (data) {                  
                try {
                    alert("Record Inserted Successfully");
                } catch (ex) {
                    alert(ex);
                }
            },
            error: function (msg) {
                alert(error);
            }
        });
```

Here the data format first i have tried is my static data and the format is

```
     data: "{'Action':'Set','VID':'3','MasterID':'52','StartID':'1','LastID':'1'}"
```

This is absolutely working fine, i have that web method called and action done.

But now i must give that values dynamically by controls. so when i tried to assign my control id to data the web method is not getting fired.

Can anyone help in the structure of data by sending thru control

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using client id in the line

```
data: { 'Action': $('#txtVoyageNumber').val(), 'VoyageMasterID': $('#txtVesselTag').val(), 'StartTerminalID': $('#txtVesselTag').val()}
```

As follows

```
 "<%= someObject.ClientID %>" 

data: { 'Action': $('#<%=txtVoyageNumber.ClientID %>').val(), 'VoyageMasterID': $('#<%=txtTag.ClientID %>').val(), 'StartTerminalID': $('#<%=txtTag.ClientID %>').val()}
```

### Edit 1

Now your function will look line

```
       $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            url: "Voyage.aspx/V_Set",
            data: { 'Action': $('#<%=txtNumber.ClientID %>').val(), 'VoyageMasterID': $('#<%=txtVesselTag.ClientID %>').val(), 'StartTerminalID': $('#<%=txtTag.ClientID %>').val()},
            async: true,
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (data) {                  
                try {
                    alert("Record Inserted Successfully");
                } catch (ex) {
                    alert(ex);
                }
            },
            error: function (msg) {
                alert(error);
            }
        });
```

Comment: No I am writing a new line for that it is same as you have written

Comment: But what i have written is not working, my webmethod is not getting fired. may be something wrong with the structure

Comment: try to replace the line with last line in my answer

Comment: try to use `#<%=ControlID.ClientID%>` instead of `#ControlID` Else set the control `ClientIdMode=Static`. Here is a link which may help you http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/34151/ASP-NET-4-0-Client-ID-Feature